# Tcolorbox split function

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm having some trouble in Overleaf (LaTex). I wan't to make a nice box kinda like the one i have made i google docs. But getting the tcolorbox to do what i want is kinda impossible for me. I have tried the split and space functions, but if they were anywere near right i have no idea.

My code so far:

```
\tcbset{colframe=black!60!white,colback=black!0!white,coltitle=white,width=(\linewidth-2mm)}

\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,title=\textbf{User},halign title=flush center, halign lower=left,lower separated=false]
Question:\\
Question:\\
Question:
\tcblower
Long and detailed answer\\
Long and detailed answer\\
Long and detailed answer\\
\end{tcolorbox}
```

[image: Google Docs box]

[image: tcolorbox]

Answer (score 2):

You are not looking for a split `tcolorbox` but a `tabularx` blended in a `tcolorbox`. Here is a basic version and a slightly more advanced version, in which you do not have to type `Question:` any more.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=User,fonttitle=\bfseries\large\sffamily,halign title=flush center,
    fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
    tabularx={lX}]
Question: &Long and detailed answer (bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla)\\
Question: &Not so long answer\\
Question: &Long and detailed answer (bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla)\\
\end{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{qbox}[2][]{title=#2,fonttitle=\bfseries\large\sffamily,halign title=flush center,
    fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
    tabularx={>{Question:}lX},#1}
\begin{qbox}{User}  
&Long and detailed answer (bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla)\\
&Not so long answer\\
&Long and detailed answer (bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla)\\
\end{qbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can be done with a *tcolorboxed* customized description environment: The description environment which keeps these margins can be easily achieved with `enumitem` package. And this `description` environment can be redefined to a `tcolorbox` environment with `\tcolorboxenvironment` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{myquestions}%
    {\begin{description}[font=\sffamily\mdseries, leftmargin=*, widest=Question:]}%
    {\end{description}}
    
\tcolorboxenvironment{myquestions}{%
    title=User, 
    fonttitle=\bfseries\large\sffamily,
    halign title=flush center,
    fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily} 
    
\begin{document}
\begin{myquestions}
\item[Question:] Long and detailed answer (bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla)
\item[Question:] Not so long answer
\item[Question:] Long and detailed answer (bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla)
\end{myquestions}
\end{document}
```

[image]